# output not showing up in console C

Tags: c, eclipse

```
    #define EOF 0
    main(){
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while ((getchar()) != EOF){
    ++nc;
    printf ("%1f\n", nc);
    }
    }
```

I copied this code from "The C Programming Language", but when I run the code, it shows nothing in the console.
 I'm using Mac and Eclipse.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What compiler you are using?

Comment: I'm using MacOSX GCC

Comment: Terminal would be quite easier, just goto your path and type `gcc <yourfile>.c` and it would produce `a.out` file. and now just execute it using. `./a.out`

Comment: You mean when the console shows up for the first time you don't see anything written there?

Comment: Yes, the console does not show anything.

Comment: **Do not `#define EOF` (it is also wrong).** Use a correct signature for `main`. Format&indent your code properly. Use the correct format specifier. Enable compiker warnings. This is Briefly: Understand what you read (it is very likely not like in the book) and use a more recent book which covers at least C99.

Comment: "I'm using MacOSX GCC" Sure it is gcc? Does it report as gcc? Not clang?

Comment: When I compile in terminal, it shows clang.

Answer (score 0):

To print a long value in C we use:

```
printf("%ld", n);
```

And not

```
printf("%1d",n);//notice you are using 1 and not l
```

Your Console wouldn't show up anything at first! Because you haven't printed anything before you request the user for a character input using getchar(). Once you give an input say 10 , you counter will be incremented to 1 and get printed

Comment: How do you give input?

Comment: With a keyboard after which you press enter

Comment: I tried doing many times. When I do ctrl-d, the loading/spinning wheel just appears. When I tried in terminal, ctrl-d only showed ^d.